# How can i determine status an do stuff in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, exists

I try to determine the status of a record is 0 or 1.

I would like to use this code seen below to determine if a specific item in this case `barcode='D189404954'` is onstock or not, if so do stuff else do nothing.

But when i run the code below it keeps saying the status is 1 even when its 0.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "watermeter");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT statuswm
FROM users
WHERE barcode='D189404954'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

// See Value for test
//var_dump($row[0]);

if ($row[0] == 1) { 
echo $row[0]; 
} else { 
echo "not in stock";

}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result code is wrong.
`==` is the comparing operator, whereas `=` is the assigning operator.

```
if ($result = 1) {
}
```

should be:

```
if ($result == 1) {
}
```

Comment: then i get the following errors:
Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\test.php on line 19

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\test.php on line 22

Comment: Add `$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);` before the if statement, then change the if statement to `if ($row[0] == 1) { echo $result; } else { echo "not in stock}`

Comment: Errors are gone, i changed the status to 1 but keep saying not in stock., thank you for helpng Ralph

Comment: Can you explain your query a little? If you're searching for the status of a user where the barcode equals `D189404954` why don't you just do `SELECT status FROM users WHERE barcode='D189404954'` Also, can you var_dump $row[0] before your if statement so we can see what value it's getting.

Comment: I get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\test.php on line 17, var_dump $row[0]?, Request to recieve the complete code ive posted changed the way you think it should work, thank you for your time Ralph but we are getting there lol

Comment: The proper syntax is `var_dump($row[0])` ;) While you're at it do `echo $row[0];` as well

Comment: i changed the echo $row[0]; wich is logical should have seen that myself even with my little skills, lol but it works fine now thank you soo much!!, but i didn't add the var_dump($row[0]) is this necessary?, when i add var_dump($row[0]); before the if statement i get result string(1) "1" 1

Comment: or is it just to see wich value we are getting?

Comment: The var_dump and echo were just so I can check whether your query is working and return the expected output. I figured out the issue in my code and it was pretty stupid lmao, I just overlooked it. You should delete the echo and vardump before the if statement, and in the if statement replace `echo $result` with `echo $row[0]`

Comment: haha, yes i did that and it works perfect now, and it make sense, thank you for your patience and help, learned alot you really helped me out, Thank you Ralph youre the best!

Comment: No worries mate, don't forget to mark as answer so this gets closed. Thanks

Comment: You see the arrow up and arrow down to the left of my code? Hit the checkmark below that and it should turn green

Comment: Thanks mate did that have a nice weekend!